# Not able to autowire fields of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, autowired

This is my implementation  of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
  @Autowired
  private JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
  @Autowired
  private JWTRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    return new JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint();
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService() {
    return new JWTUserDetailsService();
  }



  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    Implementation omitted

  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    implementation omitted
  }
}
```

This is my implementation of User Detail Service:

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import tidbit.models.Reader;
import tidbit.models.ReaderRepository;

@Component
public class JWTUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired private ReaderRepository<Reader> repository;

  public JWTUserDetailsService() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
   Implementation omitted
  }
}
```

This is my implementation of the Request Filter

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Component
public class JWTRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

  private final JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

  @Autowired
  public JWTRequestFilter(
      JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService, JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils) {
    this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
    this.jwtTokenUtils = jwtTokenUtils;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
     Implementation omitted
  }
}
```

In the *WebSecurityConfig* class I get an error for all the fields saying that Spring **cannot autowire** those fields:

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'JWTRequestFilter' found.

I was able to solve this problem for the first two fields by creating those two methods annotated with `@Bean`.
However, I don't know how solve it for *RequestFilter* since it contains a constructor with parameters that technically should be already autowired.

In general, I think that I shouldn't have this error in the first place. I have looked at some tutorials online and they were able to autowire those fields without any problems and without creating any @bean method.

**EDIT:**

Thank you for your help:

Now I get the following error

> Parameter 3 of constructor in tidbit.controllers.AuthenticationController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
> - JWTUserDetailsService: defined in file [/Users/matteoomenetti/Documents/TidBit/backend/build/classes/java/main/tidbit/config/JWTUserDetailsService.class]
> - jwtUserDetailsService: defined by method 'jwtUserDetailsService' in class path resource [tidbit/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]

It looks like I'm creating two beans of jwtUserDetailService. One is already defined in jwtUserDetailService  and the other one is defined in WebSecurityConfig with the @bean annotation. However, if I already have a bean in jwtUserDetailService why isn't WebSecurityConfig finding it?

I have noticed that if I try to autowire jwtUserDetailService in any other class (without the bean method that I created) it works perfectly, meaning that the bean is found. For some reason my WebSecurityConfig class doesn't find beans...

**SOLUTION**

The error that I get is an error only of IntelliJ. If I try to compile through the terminal I don't get any error.

Thank you everybody

Comment: remove the `@Bean` except the for the `AuthenticationManager` and `PasswordEncoder`

Comment: If I do it then it says that there are no beans for the fields of the class. However if  I try to autowire the same fields in another class it doesn't complain. It looks like that class is not able to find beans

Comment: Can you please post the implementation of class: `JWTTokenUtils`

Comment: this is not a compilation problem man, take a look again. Compilation has got nothing to do with CDI.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you stop using `new` keyword to instantiate beans. modify the following methods:

```
  @Bean
  public JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    return jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
  }

  @Bean
  public JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService() {
    return jwtUserDetailsService;
  }
```

Also, modify the following class as follows:

```
@Component
public class JWTRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
 @Autowired
  private final JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
 @Autowired
  private final JWTTokenUtils jwtTokenUtils;

 
  public JWTRequestFilter() {
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
     Implementation omitted
  }
}
```

Comment: By doing this I'm just returning the field that I am trying to autowire in the first place... Why should it work?

Comment: spring will instantiate them for you. the confusion comes when you try to instantiate components using a new keyword, spring gets confused

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new `@Bean`  except the for the `AuthenticationManager` and `PasswordEncoder`.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
  
  @Autowired
  private JWTUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
  
  @Autowired
  private JWTRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //authorizeRequests() order is important
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint); 
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        
        return provider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }
}
```

Note: you can use the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` omit it by adding the `jwtUserDetailsService` in:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
}
```

Comment: If I do it then it says that there are no beans for the fields of the class. However if I try to autowire the same fields in another class it doesn't complain. It looks like that class is not able to find beans. The solution that you proposed is my problem in the first place.

Comment: It is a perfectly working solution in prod, can you rephrase your problem?